# Add Asterisk to the end of a <label>

Tags: html, css, forms

Is it possible to add an asterisk to the end of the textstring within `<label>`?

This is what I have, but the asterisk (of course) is displayed behind the whole label:

```
<label class="xy-form-label-required" for="zipcode">
   Zip Code
   <span class="xy-form-labelinfo">
       Allowed characters a-z A-z 0-9 ,.-
       Could also be an information about the field...
   </span>
</label>
```

My CSS Code:

```
form.xy-form .xy-form-label-required:after {
    color: grey;
    content: ' *';
}
```

---

This is the result:

**Zip Code**
Allowed characters a-z A-z 0-9 ,.-
 *

This is what I want to achive without changing the html markup.

**Zip Code** *
Allowed characters a-z A-z 0-9 ,.-

Comment: CSS appends the asterix **`after`** the `<label></label>` as it is being told to. you'd either need to change your HTML markup or append it using a client-side language like jquery.

Comment: You can achieve this with javascript, unless you want it only with css and html

Comment: What is the reason to avoid changing HTML markup? I think it is possible to move asterisk where you want using position relative/negative margins or something like that, but that solution is not flexible. So, maybe it is still better to change a markup? \

Comment: The main reason why I do not want to change the markup is because I want to completely avoid floats. Maybe I should just add an extra span that only adds the asterisk in this case.

Comment: @FAngel In this case I actually changed the markup since it is impossible to achive what I want without the < selector (which will be introduced soon I think).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to change the markup like so, it is not possible to achive what I want without a < selector (which is not available yet):

```
<label class="xy-form-label" for="zipcode">
    <span class="mc-form-asterisk>Zip Code</span>
    <span class="xy-form-labelinfo">
        Allowed characters a-z A-z 0-9 ,.-
        Could also be an information about the field...
    </span>
</label>
```

My CSS Code:

```
form.xy-form .xy-form-label .xy-form-asterisk:after,
form.xy-form .xy-form-label-required:after {
    display: inline-block;
    color: grey;
    content: '\a0*';
}
```

Still not that bad I think. Nevertheless, thanks for your advice guys!

Answer (score 5):

you can simply add the following CSS code instead

```
.xy-form-label-required > span.xy-form-labelinfo:before{
  color: grey;
  content: " *";
}
```

Comment: It will not work. According to the effect which author wants to achieve span is in new line (display:block probably) and asterix after text. Not before span in new line.

Answer (score 2):

Typo apart, you want the asterisk *before* the info label:

```
.xy-form-label-required .xy-form-labelinfo:before{
    color: grey;
    content: ' *';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding asterix after element, not Text node. To achieve effect that you want you would need to use javascript i.e. something like this: http://jsbin.com/udiroz/2/edit
But I wouldn't go this way.

Don't know if this is possible in your case but I would recommend to change the markup to something like this: http://jsbin.com/udiroz/1/edit
In my opinion label is not a good place for additional informations like what chars are allowed, or not, validation errors, etc.